# django form with multiple file fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How do you handle multiple file fields in Django. For example if I had only one form field i would pass the request.FILES['file'] to a handling function. But what is the way to go when there are more files?

Answer (score 35):

I'm late to the party, but I've been trying to figure this out for a while and finally have a solution.
Have a look at the code used here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12446

You can access multipart values with getlist.  If my HTML form was:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
<input type="file" name="myfiles" multiple>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
</form>
```

My django code to process it would look like:

```
for afile in request.FILES.getlist('myfiles'):
    # do something with afile
```

Writing a form field/widget to handle this properly is my next step.  I'm still rather new to using Django, so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: How you do that ? can you show example ? i want artist user to upload multiple files in the same time in the same form .

Comment: i waste my time in others post but your post save my time to upload multiple images. thankyou

Answer (score 9):

`request.FILES.get('filename', None)` responds to the existence of a form-named field like this:

```
<input type="file" name="filename"></input>
```

If you had two such fields:

```
<input type="file" name="file1"></input>
<input type="file" name="file2"></input>
```

Then `request.FILES.get('file1', None)` and `request.FILES.get('file2', None)` should give you those files respectively.

The reason for this is multipart mime. The three parts (form data, file1, file2) should be uploaded and Django's UploadFileHandler splits this apart into `request.POST` and `request.FILES` respectively.

Comment: it not works i do it like this way.  'newsform = NewsAddForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES.get('image_news1', None), request.FILES.get('image_news2', None))'

Answer (score 1):

Here's is a good link for this answer: https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload. However, since I was not using ModelForm I had to make few changes. 
In view I have written below code and saved files to disk:

```
for each in form.cleaned_data['attachments']:
    handle_uploaded_file(each)

def uploadMyWork(request):
    from .forms import UploadFileForm, handle_uploaded_file
    print 'in uploadMyWork'

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print 'in uploadMyWork : GET'
        form = UploadFileForm()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print 'in uploadMyWork : POST'
        #for each in form.cleaned_data['attachments']:
        #    handle_uploaded_file(each)
        #return render(request, 'stitchme/uploadMyWork.html', {'msg': "file uploaded successfully"})

        if form.is_valid():
             print 'inside form valid'
             for each in form.cleaned_data['attachments']:
                 handle_uploaded_file(each)
             return render(request, 'stitchme/uploadMyWork.html', {'msg': "file uploaded successfully"})

    print 'returning to uploadmywork'
    return render(request, 'stitchme/uploadMyWork.html', {'form': form, 'msg':'hi'})
```