# Django Optional ImageField Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to set an optional imagefield in my django models. I set    blank=True,    null=True in the imagefields.After inputting the below codes I input an image in all the imagefield except place_4_view. After clicking on the upload button, I'm getting an error. What I'm I missing?

Models

```
class Findme(models.Model):
   place_2_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True,null=True)
   place_3_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True,null=True)
   place_4_view=models.ImageField (upload_to="photos",blank=True,null=True,help_text='Optional.')
```

Error when uploading

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/find/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    "Key 'place_4_view' not found in <MultiValueDict: {u'place_2_view': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: 2012-05-17-289.jpg (image/jpeg)>], u'place_3_view': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: Crimo.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>"
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 258
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Views

```
    def findpic(request):
        extra_data_context={}
           #if there's nothing in the field do nothing.
           if request.method=="POST":
              form=FindmeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
              if form.is_valid():
                 data=form.cleaned_data
                    newfindmes=Findme(
                        user=request.user,
                        pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                        place_2_view=request.FILES['room_2_view'],
                        place_3_view=request.FILES['room_3_view'],
                        place_4_view=request.FILES['room_4_view'])
                    newfindmes.save()
              extra_data_context.update({'FindmeForm':form})
         else:
             form = FindmeForm()
             extra_data_context.update({'FindmeForm':form})
        extra_data_context.update({'Findmes':Findme.objects.filter(user=request.user)})
        return render_to_response('postme.html',extra_data_context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
        {% block content %}


        <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  form action="." method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
             <div class="post-fed">{{ FindmeForm.as_p}}</div>
             <input type="submit" value="Get It"/> 
              </form>



           {% for Findme in Findmes.object_list %}
         <tr>
         <p> {{Findme.pub_date|timesince }} ago </p> 
   <p><img src="{{Findme.thumbnail_2.url}}" width="83" height="78">
    <img src="{{Findme.thumbnail_3.url}}" width="83" height="78"> {% if Findme.thumbnail_4 %} <img src="{{Findme.thumbnail_4.url}}" width="83" height="78"/>
          {% endif %}  
        <p> Created By {{ Findme.user }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Remember that running `syncdb` doesn't modify existing tables. Check your database against your model.

Comment: you mean I should set it manually?

Comment: Yes, or use some migration application like [`south`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: In my DB. ImageFields are Null=YES Default= NULL. I even deleted the db and run syncdb again and try uploading, yet I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Update the question with your view and the form you are using.

Comment: I've done that. Check it above.

Comment: You need to add the form that you are using.

Comment: How about adding required=False to the fields and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have code that expects the key to be in the form during form submission.

Edit:
Your findPic method is trying to get the field and the field isn't there when it is empty. I would recommend the use of request.FILES.get And specify a default value, or test request.FILES for the presence of the keys, or iterate over the keys themselves. Basically your code needs to be prepared for request.FILES To be empty or not contain all the fields you are trying to access.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742119/django-form-with-multiple-file-fields) for an example of using request.FILES.get and [Files Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) for other details on the request.FILES object.

Comment: This really should have been a comment since it doesn't answer anything.

Comment: If I'm to use request.FILES.get, how do I specify default value? Im confused.

Comment: answer updated to include links to an example and to docs on the request.FILES object.