# multiple file input yielding only one selected file

Tags: django, html, forms, post

I am trying to use the common `<input type="file" name="filesfield" multiple />` to upload multiple files. However I am only getting one file in the FILES['filesfield'] after selecting multiple files, and submitting the encapsulating form. I have looked around stack overflow and cant scrub anything up.

```
<form id="uploadformid" action="/basicsite/handleuploadrequest/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am using Chrome, and if it matters I am receiving the requests with django 1.6

Comment: Have a look here, maybe it leads into the right direction... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742119/django-form-with-multiple-file-fields/7355997#7355997

Comment: @Jingo, the problem is that I can not seem to get a list of files. when I look at the request while debugging django, I only see one file present, not a list of the selected files. this is more of a question of selecting multiples files in html than it is a django question. I notice that in other questions dealing with the serverside, the request contains a list of files, not just one.

Comment: So, if this is more client related, you could try to use FF or IE... and just try to name your input field "files" instead of "files[]" (one never knows... ;))

Comment: but chrome is the [most used browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) generally so it would be foolish to learn to develop this without considering the majority market share.

edit: ok ill try that

Comment: @Jingo, it is working now. I swear i tried all those configurations, but I think it was just cleaning up the code that I was able to do it properly. I think I had some conflicting inputs that couldve been the problem

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it :)