# Django handling tag "multiple" from HTML5

Tags: python, django, html

HTML5 allows uploading multiple files:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="images" multiple>
```

I created an appropriate view in views.py, lets say:

```
def sending_email(request):
    ...
    email.send()
```

There is a function *attach* to attach a single file to email. How can I attach all of the files to the email?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742119/django-form-with-multiple-file-fields/7355997#7355997 and you can try using this third party package https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload

Comment: You can use the `attach()` function multiple times, one for each attachment.

Answer (score 0):

@Svekar thank you! I just wanted to know, if I can treat variable as a list and then attach each element of it.